# PHP Slim REST Framework, .404 not found error

Tags: php, rest, slim

I am trying to use the Slim framework. and found weird behavior.

```php
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../include/db_handler.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, api v1");
    return $response;
});


$app->get('/chat', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, chat");
    return $response;
});



$app->run();
?>
```

Then If I point to

```
http://some.ip.address/v1/
```

I get

```
Hello, api v1
```

If point to

```
http://some.ip.address/v1/chat
```

I got 404 not found error.

***Why??***

Answer (score 0):

After 30seconds, I posted the question. I found an answer to this.

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/tutorial/first-app.html

You need `.htaccess` file.

Don't forget to restart your server process now you've changed the configuration!

I also have a .htaccess file in my src/public directory; this relies on Apache's rewrite module being enabled and simply makes all web requests go to index.php so that Slim can then handle all the routing for us. Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```